# Informatica pre session error: process waiting infinitely for child process to finish

Tags: powershell, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have an **powershell script** as below: this to convert the string to new line.

```
$path =  Join-Path $args[0] $args[1]
$word = "#@#@#"
$replacement = "`r`n"
$text = get-content $path 
$newText = $text -replace $word,$replacement
$newText > $path
$c=get-content $path 
Set-Content -Encoding ASCII $c -Path $path
```

and calling it from a .bat file

This works fine when called manually but going to infinite loop when called from Informatica pre session with error message :

> waiting n seconds for child process of the shell command to exit.

What can be possible gone wrong with the code ?

Comment: Try adding "exit 0" as a last line and confirm if it worked.